# Escalating from www-data to root

Tags: linux, exploit

One week ago I follow this procedure [Creating SFTP server with isolated directory access](https://akhpark.wordpress.com/2013/09/10/creating-sftp-server-with-isolated-directory-access/) ,I edit the sshd_config  but then I can't access anymore in ssh mode and consequently I can't change to root by sudo. But I still having ftp access  and I upload and use a PHP SHELL to access as www-data, but now how may I get root permission and edit the sshd_config?

My remote server is a Debian 2.6.26-1-686 #1 SMP Fri Mar 13 18:08:45 UTC 2009 i686 
Is far away and I just work in remote.

Comment: @Fis It's privilege escalation. The flavor text aside, ultimately this subgroup is the most likely to have the desired answer.

Comment: I finally got it. You cutted yourself from your server and now you are asking how to hack it in order to get access there, correct?

Comment: @user1099798 i think you have created a second account. You should speak to a mod to get your accounts merged.

Comment: If you've got FTP root access, there are various ways to escalate that to root shell access.  How to do that depends on the finer details of how your system is configured.

Comment: @Fis yes, this is correct!

Comment: @Mark I just need to edit the sshd_config file and erase the mistake I've made. I have root access password, but as you know to use I must before access as a normal user from ssh and then I can use the superuser. But when I try to use the ssh everything crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you've got FTP access as root, it's probably possible.  It's impossible to give details without knowing exactly how your server is set up, but the basic procedure is as follows:

1. Write a shell script that will make the changes you want.
2. FTP in to your server and upload the script somewhere where it will be run as root.  Options I've used in the past have included startup scripts and `/etc/cron.hourly/`.
3. If needed, do something to trigger the script you've uploaded.
4. If needed, reboot the server or otherwise cause your changes to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to fix your sshd_config as www-data. If you don't have remote console access then you'll need to speak to someone with physical access or make a trip.

Next time test out your config changes on a local machine.